# How to make element height as capital letter i.e. S?

Tags: css

I want to make span height as "S" capital letter, but it seems that it is not possible by looking into:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length

The closest being something

`height: 1.5ex`

it seems. Or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use `1em`. It is defined as the `font-size` so the capital "S" gets included.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

http://www.css3.com/css-font-stretch/

Or give it a `display:inline-block`, that should let it do what you want.

Assuming you don't want to make it a block element, then you might try:

```
.title  {
    display: inline-block; /* which allows you to set the height/width; but this isn't cross-browser, particularly as regards IE < 7 */
    line-height: 2em; /* or */
    padding-top: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}
```

But the easiest solution is to simply treat the `.title` as a block-level element, and using the appropriate heading tags `<h1>` through `<h6>`.